# Auto Layout decrease performance

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have table view that dynamically created with different cells. But it appear to be "laggy" when you scroll it fast, or where are a lot of cells on screen.

One of my suggestion, is that happening because of Auto Layout setting constraints too many time.

How can i get information about time, that was spend on building constraints?

Comment: I doubt it's because auto layout. Maybe you are doing too much work on the main thread?

Comment: @Desdenova well, maybe, but i want to check auto layout first )

Comment: Fair enough. Found this on debugging auto layout. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/TypesofErrors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH17-SW1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main methods which must be executed ac fast as posable:
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
Be sure there are not too much work on the main thread in these methods.

AutoLayout really does take a lot of main-thead work, because it is constantly performing linear calculations. If there are many views in your cell, try setting all frames in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Instruments, and choose the time profiler. Now in the app scroll up and down in your tableView a little bit, and you can check where your app is spending its time on. Check [this link on using instruments](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97886/instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started) if you want to learn some more about how to profile your app.

I highly doubt this is autolayout related however (most likely something to do with images, or doing memory intensive tasks on the main thread).

Comment: Saemlans thank you, but there is no images involved.